# TensorFlow out of Memory error running Inception v3 distributed on 4 machines

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to run Inception v3 (https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/inception) distributed on upto 32 machines.

I'm seeing out of memory error when I run it on 4 machines.

Here is the error:

```
INFO:tensorflow:Started 0 queues for processing input data.
E tensorflow/core/client/tensor_c_api.cc:485] OOM when allocating tensor with shape[2048,1001]
     [[Node: gradients/logits/logits/weights/Regularizer/L2Regularizer/L2Loss_grad/mul = Mul[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/gpu:2"](logits/logits/weights/read_S3003, gradients/logits/logits/weights/Regularizer/L2Regularizer/value_grad/tuple/control_dependency_1)]]
     [[Node: gradients/AddN_48_S3319 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:ps/replica:0/task:3/cpu:0", send_device="/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/gpu:2", send_device_incarnation=-546941133885931708, tensor_name="edge_17701_gradients/AddN_48", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:ps/replica:0/task:3/cpu:0"]()]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "imagenet_distributed_train.py", line 65, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 30, in run
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "imagenet_distributed_train.py", line 61, in main
    inception_distributed_train.train(server.target, dataset, cluster_spec)
  File "/home/ubuntu/indu/models/inception/inception/inception_distributed_train.py", line 286, in train
    loss_value, step = sess.run([train_op, global_step])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 382, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 655, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 723, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 743, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors.ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[2048,1001]
     [[Node: gradients/logits/logits/weights/Regularizer/L2Regularizer/L2Loss_grad/mul = Mul[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/gpu:2"](logits/logits/weights/read_S3003, gradients/logits/logits/weights/Regularizer/L2Regularizer/value_grad/tuple/control_dependency_1)]]
     [[Node: gradients/AddN_48_S3319 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:ps/replica:0/task:3/cpu:0", send_device="/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/gpu:2", send_device_incarnation=-546941133885931708, tensor_name="edge_17701_gradients/AddN_48", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:ps/replica:0/task:3/cpu:0"]()]]
Caused by op u'gradients/logits/logits/weights/Regularizer/L2Regularizer/L2Loss_grad/mul', defined at:
  File "imagenet_distributed_train.py", line 65, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 30, in run
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "imagenet_distributed_train.py", line 61, in main
    inception_distributed_train.train(server.target, dataset, cluster_spec)
  File "/home/ubuntu/indu/models/inception/inception/inception_distributed_train.py", line 215, in train
    grads = opt.compute_gradients(total_loss)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/sync_replicas_optimizer.py", line 229, in compute_gradients
    return self._opt.compute_gradients(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py", line 253, in compute_gradients
    colocate_gradients_with_ops=colocate_gradients_with_ops)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients.py", line 478, in gradients
    in_grads = _AsList(grad_fn(op, *out_grads))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_grad.py", line 402, in _L2LossGrad
    return op.inputs[0] * grad
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 754, in binary_op_wrapper
    return func(x, y, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 903, in _mul_dispatch
    return gen_math_ops.mul(x, y, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py", line 1427, in mul
    result = _op_def_lib.apply_op("Mul", x=x, y=y, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 703, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2310, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1232, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

...which was originally created as op u'logits/logits/weights/Regularizer/L2Regularizer/L2Loss', defined at:
  File "imagenet_distributed_train.py", line 65, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
[elided 1 identical lines from previous traceback]
  File "imagenet_distributed_train.py", line 61, in main
    inception_distributed_train.train(server.target, dataset, cluster_spec)
  File "/home/ubuntu/indu/models/inception/inception/inception_distributed_train.py", line 154, in train
    logits = inception.inference(images, num_classes, for_training=True)
  File "/home/ubuntu/indu/models/inception/inception/inception_model.py", line 87, in inference
    scope=scope)
  File "/home/ubuntu/indu/models/inception/inception/slim/inception_model.py", line 326, in inception_v3
    restore=restore_logits)
  File "/home/ubuntu/indu/models/inception/inception/slim/scopes.py", line 155, in func_with_args
    return func(*args, **current_args)
  File "/home/ubuntu/indu/models/inception/inception/slim/ops.py", line 300, in fc
    restore=restore)
  File "/home/ubuntu/indu/models/inception/inception/slim/scopes.py", line 155, in func_with_args
    return func(*args, **current_args)
  File "/home/ubuntu/indu/models/inception/inception/slim/variables.py", line 290, in variable
    trainable=trainable, collections=collections)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 830, in get_variable
    custom_getter=custom_getter)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 673, in get_variable
    custom_getter=custom_getter)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 217, in get_variable
    validate_shape=validate_shape)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 202, in _true_getter
    caching_device=caching_device, validate_shape=validate_shape)
```

I'm using EC2 G2.8XL instances. These instances have:

1. Intel Xeon E5-2670 (Sandy Bridge) Processors
2. 60 GB memory and
3. Four GK104GL [GRID K520] GPU with 4 GB memory on each of them.
4. 10 Gigabit NIC

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS on these machines.

I'm running one worker per GPU. So, in total there is 16 workers.

I'm running one PS per machine. So, 4 PS in total.

I'm using a batch size of 8. (4 machines run out of memory with a batch size of 8. 32 machines run out of memory even with a batch size of 2).

Installed version of CUDA and cuDNN:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-16-180:~$ ls -l /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcud*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 322936 Aug 15 2015 /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudadevrt.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16 Aug 15 2015 /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudart.so -> libcudart.so.7.5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 19 Aug 15 2015 /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudart.so.7.5 -> libcudart.so.7.5.18
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 383336 Aug 15 2015 /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudart.so.7.5.18
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 720192 Aug 15 2015 /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudart_static.a
```

I installed TensorFlow from https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/gpu/tensorflow-0.10.0rc0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-16-180:~$ python -c "import tensorflow; print(tensorflow.version)"
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so locally
0.10.0rc0
```

Could someone please help me figure how how to fix this and run Inception v3 in a cluster with 32 machines?

More info:
Here are the commands I'm executing on the machines in the cluster:

```
On machine1:
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES='' python imagenet_distributed_train.py --ps_hosts=worker1:2222,worker2:2222,worker3:2222,worker4:2222 --worker_hosts=worker1:2230,worker1:2231,worker1:2232,worker1:2233,worker2:2230,worker2:2231,worker2:2232,worker2:2233,worker3:2230,worker3:2231,worker3:2232,worker3:2233,worker4:2230,worker4:2231,worker4:2232,worker4:2233 --job_name=ps --task_id=0 2>&1 &
python imagenet_distributed_train.py --batch_size=8 --data_dir=datadir --ps_hosts=worker1:2222,worker2:2222,worker3:2222,worker4:2222 --worker_hosts=worker1:2230,worker1:2231,worker1:2232,worker1:2233,worker2:2230,worker2:2231,worker2:2232,worker2:2233,worker3:2230,worker3:2231,worker3:2232,worker3:2233,worker4:2230,worker4:2231,worker4:2232,worker4:2233 --job_name=worker --task_id=0 > /tmp/worker0 2>&1 &
python imagenet_distributed_train.py --batch_size=8 --data_dir=datadir --ps_hosts=worker1:2222,worker2:2222,worker3:2222,worker4:2222 --worker_hosts=worker1:2230,worker1:2231,worker1:2232,worker1:2233,worker2:2230,worker2:2231,worker2:2232,worker2:2233,worker3:2230,worker3:2231,worker3:2232,worker3:2233,worker4:2230,worker4:2231,worker4:2232,worker4:2233 --job_name=worker --task_id=1 > /tmp/worker1 2>&1 &
python imagenet_distributed_train.py --batch_size=8 --data_dir=datadir --ps_hosts=worker1:2222,worker2:2222,worker3:2222,worker4:2222 --worker_hosts=worker1:2230,worker1:2231,worker1:2232,worker1:2233,worker2:2230,worker2:2231,worker2:2232,worker2:2233,worker3:2230,worker3:2231,worker3:2232,worker3:2233,worker4:2230,worker4:2231,worker4:2232,worker4:2233 --job_name=worker --task_id=2 > /tmp/worker2 2>&1 &
python imagenet_distributed_train.py --batch_size=8 --data_dir=datadir --ps_hosts=worker1:2222,worker2:2222,worker3:2222,worker4:2222 --worker_hosts=worker1:2230,worker1:2231,worker1:2232,worker1:2233,worker2:2230,worker2:2231,worker2:2232,worker2:2233,worker3:2230,worker3:2231,worker3:2232,worker3:2233,worker4:2230,worker4:2231,worker4:2232,worker4:2233 --job_name=worker --task_id=3 > /tmp/worker3 2>&1 &


On machine2:
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES='' python imagenet_distributed_train.py --ps_hosts=worker1:2222,worker2:2222,worker3:2222,worker4:2222 --worker_hosts=worker1:2230,worker1:2231,worker1:2232,worker1:2233,worker2:2230,worker2:2231,worker2:2232,worker2:2233,worker3:2230,worker3:2231,worker3:2232,worker3:2233,worker4:2230,worker4:2231,worker4:2232,worker4:2233 --job_name=ps --task_id=1 2>&1 &
python imagenet_distributed_train.py --batch_size=8 --data_dir=datadir --ps_hosts=worker1:2222,worker2:2222,worker3:2222,worker4:2222 --worker_hosts=worker1:2230,worker1:2231,worker1:2232,worker1:2233,worker2:2230,worker2:2231,worker2:2232,worker2:2233,worker3:2230,worker3:2231,worker3:2232,worker3:2233,worker4:2230,worker4:2231,worker4:2232,worker4:2233 --job_name=worker --task_id=4 > /tmp/worker4 2>&1 &
python imagenet_distributed_train.py --batch_size=8 --data_dir=datadir --ps_hosts=worker1:2222,worker2:2222,worker3:2222,worker4:2222 --worker_hosts=worker1:2230,worker1:2231,worker1:2232,worker1:2233,worker2:2230,worker2:2231,worker2:2232,worker2:2233,worker3:2230,worker3:2231,worker3:2232,worker3:2233,worker4:2230,worker4:2231,worker4:2232,worker4:2233 --job_name=worker --task_id=5 > /tmp/worker5 2>&1 &
python imagenet_distributed_train.py --batch_size=8 --data_dir=datadir --ps_hosts=worker1:2222,worker2:2222,worker3:2222,worker4:2222 --worker_hosts=worker1:2230,worker1:2231,worker1:2232,worker1:2233,worker2:2230,worker2:2231,worker2:2232,worker2:2233,worker3:2230,worker3:2231,worker3:2232,worker3:2233,worker4:2230,worker4:2231,worker4:2232,worker4:2233 --job_name=worker --task_id=6 > /tmp/worker6 2>&1 &
python imagenet_distributed_train.py --batch_size=8 --data_dir=datadir --ps_hosts=worker1:2222,worker2:2222,worker3:2222,worker4:2222 --worker_hosts=worker1:2230,worker1:2231,worker1:2232,worker1:2233,worker2:2230,worker2:2231,worker2:2232,worker2:2233,worker3:2230,worker3:2231,worker3:2232,worker3:2233,worker4:2230,worker4:2231,worker4:2232,worker4:2233 --job_name=worker --task_id=7 > /tmp/worker7 2>&1 &


On machine3:
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES='' python imagenet_distributed_train.py --ps_hosts=worker1:2222,worker2:2222,worker3:2222,worker4:2222 --worker_hosts=worker1:2230,worker1:2231,worker1:2232,worker1:2233,worker2:2230,worker2:2231,worker2:2232,worker2:2233,worker3:2230,worker3:2231,worker3:2232,worker3:2233,worker4:2230,worker4:2231,worker4:2232,worker4:2233 --job_name=ps --task_id=2 2>&1 &
python imagenet_distributed_train.py --batch_size=8 --data_dir=datadir --ps_hosts=worker1:2222,worker2:2222,worker3:2222,worker4:2222 --worker_hosts=worker1:2230,worker1:2231,worker1:2232,worker1:2233,worker2:2230,worker2:2231,worker2:2232,worker2:2233,worker3:2230,worker3:2231,worker3:2232,worker3:2233,worker4:2230,worker4:2231,worker4:2232,worker4:2233 --job_name=worker --task_id=8 > /tmp/worker8 2>&1 &
python imagenet_distributed_train.py --batch_size=8 --data_dir=datadir --ps_hosts=worker1:2222,worker2:2222,worker3:2222,worker4:2222 --worker_hosts=worker1:2230,worker1:2231,worker1:2232,worker1:2233,worker2:2230,worker2:2231,worker2:2232,worker2:2233,worker3:2230,worker3:2231,worker3:2232,worker3:2233,worker4:2230,worker4:2231,worker4:2232,worker4:2233 --job_name=worker --task_id=9 > /tmp/worker9 2>&1 &
python imagenet_distributed_train.py --batch_size=8 --data_dir=datadir --ps_hosts=worker1:2222,worker2:2222,worker3:2222,worker4:2222 --worker_hosts=worker1:2230,worker1:2231,worker1:2232,worker1:2233,worker2:2230,worker2:2231,worker2:2232,worker2:2233,worker3:2230,worker3:2231,worker3:2232,worker3:2233,worker4:2230,worker4:2231,worker4:2232,worker4:2233 --job_name=worker --task_id=10 > /tmp/worker10 2>&1 &
python imagenet_distributed_train.py --batch_size=8 --data_dir=datadir --ps_hosts=worker1:2222,worker2:2222,worker3:2222,worker4:2222 --worker_hosts=worker1:2230,worker1:2231,worker1:2232,worker1:2233,worker2:2230,worker2:2231,worker2:2232,worker2:2233,worker3:2230,worker3:2231,worker3:2232,worker3:2233,worker4:2230,worker4:2231,worker4:2232,worker4:2233 --job_name=worker --task_id=11 > /tmp/worker11 2>&1 &


On machine4:
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES='' python imagenet_distributed_train.py --ps_hosts=worker1:2222,worker2:2222,worker3:2222,worker4:2222 --worker_hosts=worker1:2230,worker1:2231,worker1:2232,worker1:2233,worker2:2230,worker2:2231,worker2:2232,worker2:2233,worker3:2230,worker3:2231,worker3:2232,worker3:2233,worker4:2230,worker4:2231,worker4:2232,worker4:2233 --job_name=ps --task_id=3 2>&1 &
python imagenet_distributed_train.py --batch_size=8 --data_dir=datadir --ps_hosts=worker1:2222,worker2:2222,worker3:2222,worker4:2222 --worker_hosts=worker1:2230,worker1:2231,worker1:2232,worker1:2233,worker2:2230,worker2:2231,worker2:2232,worker2:2233,worker3:2230,worker3:2231,worker3:2232,worker3:2233,worker4:2230,worker4:2231,worker4:2232,worker4:2233 --job_name=worker --task_id=12 > /tmp/worker12 2>&1 &
python imagenet_distributed_train.py --batch_size=8 --data_dir=datadir --ps_hosts=worker1:2222,worker2:2222,worker3:2222,worker4:2222 --worker_hosts=worker1:2230,worker1:2231,worker1:2232,worker1:2233,worker2:2230,worker2:2231,worker2:2232,worker2:2233,worker3:2230,worker3:2231,worker3:2232,worker3:2233,worker4:2230,worker4:2231,worker4:2232,worker4:2233 --job_name=worker --task_id=13 > /tmp/worker13 2>&1 &
python imagenet_distributed_train.py --batch_size=8 --data_dir=datadir --ps_hosts=worker1:2222,worker2:2222,worker3:2222,worker4:2222 --worker_hosts=worker1:2230,worker1:2231,worker1:2232,worker1:2233,worker2:2230,worker2:2231,worker2:2232,worker2:2233,worker3:2230,worker3:2231,worker3:2232,worker3:2233,worker4:2230,worker4:2231,worker4:2232,worker4:2233 --job_name=worker --task_id=14 > /tmp/worker14 2>&1 &
python imagenet_distributed_train.py --batch_size=8 --data_dir=datadir --ps_hosts=worker1:2222,worker2:2222,worker3:2222,worker4:2222 --worker_hosts=worker1:2230,worker1:2231,worker1:2232,worker1:2233,worker2:2230,worker2:2231,worker2:2232,worker2:2233,worker3:2230,worker3:2231,worker3:2232,worker3:2233,worker4:2230,worker4:2231,worker4:2232,worker4:2233 --job_name=worker --task_id=15 > /tmp/worker15 2>&1 &
```

**Update 1:**

I tried the following experiments:

Experiment 1:

- Worker1, worker2, worker3 and worker4 on machine1
- ps1 or machine1, ps2 on machine2, ps3 on machine3, ps4 on machine4.

This is same as the 4 machine configuration that failed except that workers from 3 of the four machines are removed. 
Worker load on machine1 remains the same. Communication load on machine1 (talking to four ps) remains the same.
I expected this to run out of memory but this worked perfectly fine.

Experiment 2:

- Worker1, worker2, worker3 and worker4 on machine1.
- ps1 (only ps) on machine2.

This worked like charm and learning rate was faster than experiment 1.

Given this, I wonder why four machine using all four GPUs run out of memory.

Comment: One suggestion: try setting `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0`  for the first task on each machine, `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1` for the second task, etc. This will change the GPU naming (each worker task will have a single GPU device called `/gpu:0`, corresponding to the single visible device), but it should prevent the different TensorFlow processes from interfering with each other.

Comment: @mrry: That fixed the issue. Thanks!

I had previously changed `with tf.device('/job:worker/task:%d' % FLAGS.task_id):` to `with tf.device('/gpu:%d' % gpunum):` in inception_distributed_train.py. Gpunum was `gpunum = FLAGS.task_id%4`. Wonder why that and doing the same using `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=gpunum` are not the same.

Comment: I added some theories in my answer... I think there are some issues when multiple TensorFlow processes share the same physical device, but I'm not 100% what would cause the failure you're seeing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, setting `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=i` for the `i`th task on each machine fixes the problem. This has the effect of changing the GPU naming (so each worker task has a single GPU device named `"/gpu:0"`, corresponding to the single visible device in that task), but it prevents the different TensorFlow processes on the same machine from interfering with each other.

The following commands should work:

```
# On machine1:
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES='' python imagenet_distributed_train.py --ps_hosts=worker1:2222,worker2:2222,worker3:2222,worker4:2222 --worker_hosts=worker1:2230,worker1:2231,worker1:2232,worker1:2233,worker2:2230,worker2:2231,worker2:2232,worker2:2233,worker3:2230,worker3:2231,worker3:2232,worker3:2233,worker4:2230,worker4:2231,worker4:2232,worker4:2233 --job_name=ps --task_id=0 2>&1 &
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0 python imagenet_distributed_train.py --batch_size=8 --data_dir=datadir --ps_hosts=worker1:2222,worker2:2222,worker3:2222,worker4:2222 --worker_hosts=worker1:2230,worker1:2231,worker1:2232,worker1:2233,worker2:2230,worker2:2231,worker2:2232,worker2:2233,worker3:2230,worker3:2231,worker3:2232,worker3:2233,worker4:2230,worker4:2231,worker4:2232,worker4:2233 --job_name=worker --task_id=0 > /tmp/worker0 2>&1 &
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1 python imagenet_distributed_train.py --batch_size=8 --data_dir=datadir --ps_hosts=worker1:2222,worker2:2222,worker3:2222,worker4:2222 --worker_hosts=worker1:2230,worker1:2231,worker1:2232,worker1:2233,worker2:2230,worker2:2231,worker2:2232,worker2:2233,worker3:2230,worker3:2231,worker3:2232,worker3:2233,worker4:2230,worker4:2231,worker4:2232,worker4:2233 --job_name=worker --task_id=1 > /tmp/worker1 2>&1 &
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=2 python imagenet_distributed_train.py --batch_size=8 --data_dir=datadir --ps_hosts=worker1:2222,worker2:2222,worker3:2222,worker4:2222 --worker_hosts=worker1:2230,worker1:2231,worker1:2232,worker1:2233,worker2:2230,worker2:2231,worker2:2232,worker2:2233,worker3:2230,worker3:2231,worker3:2232,worker3:2233,worker4:2230,worker4:2231,worker4:2232,worker4:2233 --job_name=worker --task_id=2 > /tmp/worker2 2>&1 &
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=3 python imagenet_distributed_train.py --batch_size=8 --data_dir=datadir --ps_hosts=worker1:2222,worker2:2222,worker3:2222,worker4:2222 --worker_hosts=worker1:2230,worker1:2231,worker1:2232,worker1:2233,worker2:2230,worker2:2231,worker2:2232,worker2:2233,worker3:2230,worker3:2231,worker3:2232,worker3:2233,worker4:2230,worker4:2231,worker4:2232,worker4:2233 --job_name=worker --task_id=3 > /tmp/worker3 2>&1 &


# On machine2:
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES='' python imagenet_distributed_train.py --ps_hosts=worker1:2222,worker2:2222,worker3:2222,worker4:2222 --worker_hosts=worker1:2230,worker1:2231,worker1:2232,worker1:2233,worker2:2230,worker2:2231,worker2:2232,worker2:2233,worker3:2230,worker3:2231,worker3:2232,worker3:2233,worker4:2230,worker4:2231,worker4:2232,worker4:2233 --job_name=ps --task_id=1 2>&1 &
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0 python imagenet_distributed_train.py --batch_size=8 --data_dir=datadir --ps_hosts=worker1:2222,worker2:2222,worker3:2222,worker4:2222 --worker_hosts=worker1:2230,worker1:2231,worker1:2232,worker1:2233,worker2:2230,worker2:2231,worker2:2232,worker2:2233,worker3:2230,worker3:2231,worker3:2232,worker3:2233,worker4:2230,worker4:2231,worker4:2232,worker4:2233 --job_name=worker --task_id=4 > /tmp/worker4 2>&1 &
...
```

The precise reason for this not totally clear, but two possibilities are:

1. In your initial setup, all four worker tasks on each machine create a device object for each GPU on the machine, and they may be attempting to allocate 4x the memory on each device.
2. When all four GPUs on the system are visible to each process, TensorFlow's placer has more options, and depending on your setup/training program it may inadvertently  place ops from two worker tasks on the same GPU.

Answer (score 2):

4GB GPU memory is a bit low for those models, which were tuned on GPU cards with 12GB GPU memory. The small batch size lowers the activation size, but not the parameter size.

Once you make sure there is unnecessary use of memory in your model, you can try to disable Cudnn conv scratch memory, by using

TF_CUDNN_WORKSPACE_LIMIT_IN_MB=0

That disables use of scratch memory in your model. Your model will be slower, but hopefully it has the slight edge to at least finish.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you please check 'update 1' on the question. If number of parameters being large is the issue, shouldn't those experiments run out of memory too?

Given this, should I still try setting TF_CUDNN_WORKSPACE_LIMIT_IN_MB to 0. If yes, is there a way to do this without compiling from source?

Comment: TF_CUDNN_WORKSPACE_LIMIT_IN_MB is an environmental variable. You don't have to compile from source. I agree that there is no guarantee that this would solve the problem. But it's a good idea to try anyway. If you are only a little short on memory, it might work.